# How to Control Visual Studio Code Extension Intellisense?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

i want to make my extension

I want to suggest "CompletionList" to users.
users can run "editor.action.triggerSuggest"

The process of my extensions as is follows

1. users write some texts
2. if he press "completion command",
3. vscode extension provides Completion
4. and executeCommand("editor.action.triggerSuggest")

But i encounter some issues.
When a specific character is already entered, no matter how much I create CompletionItems, they won't appear unless that specific character is included in the suggestions. For instance, if the cursor is positioned right after the letter 'r' in the word 'for,' the suggestion list won't appear, but if the cursor is one space after 'r,' the suggestion list appears as expected

When the cursor is right behind the text

[image: img]

When there is a space

[image: img]

if there is a way that solve this issue?

---

**Edit**

When I performed a similar task with 'NT,' the Code Completion items appeared with the character 'NT' in CodeCompletion. Therefore, I suspect that in vscode Intellisense, based on the cursor position, it may be looking for completions specifically related to 'NT' since the cursor is right after 'T' in 'NT.' In conclusion, when vscode provides triggerSuggest internally, it seems to be influenced by the preceding characters, offering only triggerSuggest items related to them. Is there a way to address this issue?

When the cursor is right behind the text

[image: img]

When there is a space

[image: img]

---

**Edit**

```js
  const completionTest = vscode.commands.registerCommand("sb.subhotkey", () => {
    // Remove existing completions
    const disposable = vscode.Disposable.from(CompletionProvider);
    disposable.dispose();

    // Sort candidates based on their values in descending order
    candidates.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);
    
    // Register new completion provider
    CompletionProvider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(
        "smallbasic",
        {
            provideCompletionItems(): vscode.ProviderResult<
                vscode.CompletionItem[] | vscode.CompletionList
            > {
                const CompletionItems: vscode.CompletionItem[] = [];
                for (const { key, value } of candidates) {
                    const completion = new vscode.CompletionItem(key);
                    const completionDocs = new vscode.MarkdownString(value.toString());
                    completion.documentation = completionDocs;
                    CompletionItems.push(completion);
                }
                return CompletionItems;
            },
        },
        "."
    );
    // Triggest Suggest command
    vscode.commands.executeCommand("editor.action.triggerSuggest");
});
```

Candidates are structured as follows:

```
0:{key: '[T, ID]', value: 1444}

1:{key: '[T, (, NT, Expr, T, )]', value: 982}

2:{key: '[T, STR]', value: 697}

3:{key: '[T, NUM]', value: 227}

4:{key: '[T, ID, NT, Idxs]', value: 152}
```

Comment: do you supply completion items while typing or does the user has to ask for completion items, add log statements that show when your completion function is called, sometimes Emmet overrules any other CompletionItemProvider, maybe there are others (VSC native) that do this too.

Comment: @rioV8 While I'm not sure if the response addresses the question correctly, when I performed a similar task with 'NT,' the Code Completion items appeared with the character 'NT' in CodeCompletion. In this case, considering the cursor's position in vscode Intellisense, it might be searching specifically for completions related to 'NT' due to the cursor being right after 'T' in 'NT.' However, I would like it to show completions even if they are not directly related to the 'NT' item.

Comment: Additionally, I have attached example photos to the original post

Comment: your code decide based on the context (position of cursor) what to put in the Completion List, you can put anything in there, if you don't show code we can only guess what you do

Comment: @rioV8 "I added my code above. This is my code. Sorry for the delay in response

Comment: don't use variable names that start with capitals: `CompletionProvider`, `CompletionItems`, there is no need to dispose the `CompletionItemProvider` each time, for sorting you can use the `sortText` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the fuzzy search VSC performs on all shown lists, like the Command Palette.

You type part of the text you search, characters don't need to next to each other, Capitals of Camel case class name, function name.

If you want member suggestions your completion provider is triggered by `.` character and then fuzzy search uses all word characters before the cursor, if there are no characters until `.` you see the whole list, it gets filtered when you type.

You need to set the `filterText` property of the completion item.

- are there word chars before the cursor: set `filterText` to word chars + `key`
- are there **NO** word chars before the cursor: set `filterText` to `key`

Comment: What you're saying seems to mean, for example, if there is a word like 'fo' among the word chars before the cursor, set completion.filterText to 'fo' + key. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: @SeokwooYang Use **all** word characters before the cursor as a prefix for the `key` and assign it to `filterText`, then the user can type and filter the list

Comment: I was able to solve it thanks to your help! By using the 'filterText' method and specifying the desired prefix, I could customize the code suggestions to appear in the way I wanted! I really appreciate your kind assistance, and I apologize for the delayed response